# concept for creating a small game using sheetengine

Tags: javascript, sheetengine

I am creating a small isometric online game and would like to use the [sheetengine](https://sheetengine.codeplex.com).

Here is my basic idea:

1. create a scene of the size approx 4100x3000
2. creating 75x45 basesheets (since the World is 75x45 fixed and wont increase)
3. To place some objects on the map I use the class **Sheet** (I will only change the size and the position of the sheets after placing them)
4. For Zoom In/Out I actually redraw the whole scene - so I destroy all the basesheets and then place them from new in a bigger size - as for the Sheets ... I'm trying to change their size and their position
5. For moving the map I'm using the method **scene.setCenter** - since the scene is already of that huge size, I don't have to redraw the map after the translation

**My questions:**

1. How can I change the position and the size of the sheet after placing them? I know that using the SheetObject you can do all that, but I will have a huge amount of objects placed and the calculation time is taking to long with SheetObjects. That's why I'm not using that class... An object of the "class" Sheet has a property

   > sheet.data.translationx

   I coudl also manipulate this and thsi works, but there must be method and I couldn't find it
2. Is there a better way of handling big scenes with sheetengine? I mean creating a scene that big is definitely not a good Idea. But if I make it smaller, I will not see the whole world after a translation - so how could I handle it differently?